# Execute function passed by octals

Tags: php

I have a code

```
<?php
eval('print '.$_GET['email'].";"); 
?>
```

when I do

```
http://localhost/1.php?email=phpinfo()
```

I get executed phpinfo() function

But if I do

```
http://localhost/1.php?email="\160\150\160\151\156\146\157\050\051"
```

I get only string "phpinfo()"

So how to execute phpinfo() function using only octals?

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
  http://localhost/1.php?email=\160\150\160\151\156\146\157\050\051

<?php

  $url=urldecode($_GET['email']);
  $func_name=stripcslashes($url);
  eval('print '.$func_name.";"); 

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, but i wan't change my code, i need understand why octals is not executed in my way

Answer (score 0):

Ok im done by myself

```
http://localhost/1.php?email=${"\160\150\160\151\156\146\157"()}
```

do the trick